# Is there a way to have markup as the value to schema.org itemprop?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

Is there a way to have markup as the value to a schema.org `itemprop` node? E.g. this works:

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

But can you make this work:

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre"> <p>Science</p> <h2>fiction</h2></span>      <<====
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML spec [defines what the property value is of an element with an `itemscope` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#concept-property-value), and it says for elements other than `meta`, `audio`, `embed`, `iframe`, `img`, `source`, `track`, `video`, `a`, `area`, `link`, `object`, `data`, `meter`, or `time`, “*The value is the element's textContent*“.

So the HTML spec requires consumers of microdata markup to ignore markup inside the `span` element in `<span itemprop="genre"> <p>Science</p> <h2>fiction…` and just use the text.